# Popcorn.js - How do I remove a cue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popcornjs

I have added several cues to a video using popcorn JS.

How do I remove or modify a specific cue?

Comment: Is there an example of what you did, as a block of code in the question or possibly a link?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried! It helps earning that answer! :) Also a good read is http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've added a cue to your Popcorn instance, you can remove it the same way you remove any plugin event, with the `removeTrackEvent` method.

```
popcorn.removeTrackEvent(eventId);
```

The trick is getting the id of the event you want to remove. Popcorn doesn't really provide an easy way to search for track events, so you'll want to get the id and hold on to it at the time the event is created.

```
popcorn.cue(1, function() {
   console.log('Do that voodoo.');
});
var eventId = popcorn.getLastTrackEventId();
// some time later...
popcorn.removeTrackEvent(eventId);
```

The Popcorn API was originally designed to be chainable, so the `cue` method returns the Popcorn instance. That's why you need the separate call to `getLastTrackEventId`.

If you want to modify a cue, it depends on whether you want to take the same function and move it...

```
popcorn.cue(eventId, 2); //move it to 2 seconds
```

Or change the function:

```
popcorn.cue(eventId, function() { console.log('hi!'); }); //time stays the same
```

Comment: Works even with footnote plugin, so no need to write own plugin. Thx.    var eventId = popcornObj.getLastTrackEventId();
 popcornObj.removeTrackEvent(eventId);
 
 //show new footnote
 popcornObj.footnote({
  start: timeFrom,
  end: timeTo,
  text: actionName,
  target: "footnotediv"
 });

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if you've used popcorn to setup an video element like `var pop = Popcorn(#videoElementId);` then called some methods on it like `pop.footnote({...})` or what have you, then you need to just delete the code that set them up, so they're not there anymore.

If instead you're asking okay I made a footnote show, and now I want to replace it, or hide it, then you probably need to add another cue that targets the same div element that you wanted to replace. Try a footnote with text set to and empty string.